# Creating a list for column names of dataframe while changing multiple values into one value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe named df which is the combination of multiple .csv files, so for certain index in each file there are several column names. Lets say column names are A, B, C, D, E for different .csv files. I want to change all A, B, C, D, E s in column names into F.

I tried this;

> `df = pd.read_csv(path + config['file'] + '.csv')`

`list = [c.replace('A', 'F') for c in df.columns]`

But could not figure out an easy one line way to change B, C, D, E values into F.

Helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

define col names first:

```
to_replace_cols=['A','B','C','D','E']

df.columns = ['F' if i in to_replace_cols else i for i in df.columns]

#one line
df.columns = ['F' if i in ['A','B','C','D','E'] else i for i in df.columns]
```